# Как сделать inline-кнопку Telegram Bot API с новой строки в Java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Как сделать inline-кнопку Telegram API с новой строки в Java?

Пишу на JDK11.

Заранее спасибо!

```
public static SendMessage sendInlineKeyBoardMessage(long chatId) {

    InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(); //Создаем объект разметки клавиатуры
    InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton1 = new InlineKeyboardButton(); //Создаем кнопку
    InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton2 = new InlineKeyboardButton(); //Создаем кнопку
    InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton3 = new InlineKeyboardButton(); //Создаем кнопку
    InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton4 = new InlineKeyboardButton(); //Создаем кнопку
    InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton5 = new InlineKeyboardButton(); //Создаем кнопку

    inlineKeyboardButton1.setText("Понедельник"); //Текст самой кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton1.setCallbackData("Ответ"); //Отклик на нажатие кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton2.setText("Вторник"); //Текст самой кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton2.setCallbackData("Ответ"); //Отклик на нажатие кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton3.setText("Среда"); //Текст самой кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton3.setCallbackData("Ответ"); //Отклик на нажатие кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton4.setText("Четверг"); //Текст самой кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton4.setCallbackData("Ответ"); //Отклик на нажатие кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton5.setText("Пятница"); //Текст самой кнопки
    inlineKeyboardButton5.setCallbackData("Ответ"); //Отклик на нажатие кнопки

    List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboardButtonsRow1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboardButtonsRow2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboardButtonsRow3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboardButtonsRow4 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboardButtonsRow5 = new ArrayList<>();

    keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton1);
    keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton2);
    keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton3);
    keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton4);
    keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton5);

    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowList = new ArrayList<>(); //Создаём ряд
    rowList.add(keyboardButtonsRow1);
    rowList.add(keyboardButtonsRow2);
    rowList.add(keyboardButtonsRow3);
    rowList.add(keyboardButtonsRow4);
    rowList.add(keyboardButtonsRow5);

    inlineKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(rowList);

    return new SendMessage().setChatId(chatId).setText("Выбери день недели:").setReplyMarkup(inlineKeyboardMarkup);
} // Кнопки
```

Comment: сам API не знаю, но предположу, что нужно добавлять не только в `keyboardButtonsRow1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопки - это массив массивов, где каждый вложенный массив является новым рядом (строкой) кнопок. Судя по представленному коду, все кнопки добавляются у вас в один ряд - `keyboardButtonsRow1`:

```
keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton1);
keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton2);
keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton3);
keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton4);
keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton5);
```

Соответственно, следующий код будет отображать по одной кнопке на строку:

```
keyboardButtonsRow1.add(inlineKeyboardButton1);
keyboardButtonsRow2.add(inlineKeyboardButton2);
keyboardButtonsRow3.add(inlineKeyboardButton3);
keyboardButtonsRow4.add(inlineKeyboardButton4);
keyboardButtonsRow5.add(inlineKeyboardButton5);
```

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл косяк